# TFS SharePoint default collection site not accessible from public IP

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I need the community's help on this.

We have TFS 2010 and SharePoint services installed on a server in our internal network and I can access it fine via `servername/sites/DefaultCollection/`.

We're trying to give access to external teams to the same site.
When we try to access `publicIP/sites/DefaultCollection/`
we get a 404 NOT FOUND error (publicIP points to the IP of the TFS server).

I noticed that in Team Foundation Server Administration Console in the [General] tab is says:

> DefaultCollection URL: `servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/`

While at the [SharePoint Site] tab under Default Site Location shows: `servername/sites/DefaultCollection/`.

When I try locally `servername/tfs/DefaultCollection/` I get the same error (404 NOT FOUND).

So it seems like when we try to visit `publicIP/sites/DefaultCollection/` it actually goes to `publicIP/tfs/DefaultCollection/` without the address changing on the browser.

How can I make this work?
Any help will deeply appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Edward.. I always wonder with they don't use a WYSIWUG editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set up alternate access mappings in Sharepoint?

1. Go to Administrative Tools -> Sharepoint Central Administration.
2. Click on the "Operations" tab
3. In the "Global Configuration" section, select "Alternate access mappings"
4. Select "Edit Public URLs"

There you can add a new URL for the "Internet" site so that external users can access Sharepoint.  Note that this URL may need to be a fully qualified domain name, not an IP address.  (However I've never tested with an IP address.)